# Elementary Model Theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm working through section 4.3. on model theory from Dirk van Dalen's *Logic and Structure* (fifth ed.) and am struggling with van Dalen's sometimes sloppy way of presenting proofs.

As usual let a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ be *elementarily embeddable* in a structure $\mathfrak{B}$ ($\mathfrak{A} \prec \mathfrak{B}$), if $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to some elementary substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$. Furthermore, let $\hat{\mathfrak{A}}$ be the structure resulting from $\mathfrak{A}$ by adding all the members of its domain as constants.

One crucial lemma in van Dalen's treatment of non-standard models is the following:

> $\mathfrak{A} \prec \mathfrak{B} \Leftrightarrow \hat{\mathfrak{B}} \models Th(\hat{\mathfrak{A}})$

where $\models$ is the usual first-order satisfaction relation generalized for sets of sentences and $Th(\mathfrak{A})$ the set of sentences true in $\mathfrak{A}$.

Now, my main source of confusion in the proof of the left-to-right direction is that van Dalen assumes without proof that $\hat{\mathfrak{A}} \models \phi(\bar{a_1}, \ldots, \bar{a_n})$ entails $ \mathfrak{A} \models \phi(\bar{a_1}, \ldots, \bar{a_n})$ (let $\vec{a_i}$ abbreviate the sequence $\bar{a_1}, \ldots, \bar{a_n}$) and $\mathfrak{B} \models \phi(\vec{a_i})$ entails $\hat{\mathfrak{B}} \models \phi(\vec{a_i})$. Why is that so?

Concerning the right-to-left direction it's easy to prove that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$ and that $\mathfrak{A} \models \phi(\vec{a_i}) \Rightarrow \mathfrak{B} \models \phi(\vec{a_i})$ for all ${a_i}$ from the domain of $\mathfrak{A}$. But I don't get the converse direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean $\hat {\mathfrak A} \models \phi(\bar a_1, ..., \bar a_n)$ entails $\mathfrak A \models \phi(\bar a_1, ..., \bar a_n)$. If this is not clear, then try to prove it by induction on $\phi$. The proof might depend on exact definitions van Dalen uses. So you are better of including them in the question.

Comment: Extending language $\mathfrak{L}$ by adding constant symbols for all elements $a\in A$ of the domain of some structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and interpretating these as the original elemnts $a\in A$ is just an equivalent (and sometimes more conveneint if u want to avoid explicit variable assignment functions) way for assigning truth values - to sentences.

See for instance *"There is a second common approach to defining truth values that does not rely on variable assignment functions.."* at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Answer (score 1):

As per Yoneda's comment, you have to consider the basic definition of *interpretation*; see Ch.3.4 **Semantics**, page 64-on, at page 65 :

> Let us now present a definition of interpretation for the general case. Consider [the *structure*] $\mathfrak{A} = \langle A,R_1,\ldots, R_n,F_1,\ldots, F_m, \{ c_i |i \in I \} \rangle$ of a given similarity type $\langle r_1,\ldots, r_n; a_1,\ldots, a_m; |I| \rangle$ [where, see page 54 : ] the $c_i$ are elements of A (constants).

I think that it is better to call them *distinguished elements*, in order to avoid confusion with the *constants* $\overline c_i$, which are symbols of the language [see page 56]; of course, the $c_i$'s are the *reference* of the $\overline c_i$'s.

The corresponding language has predicate symbols $\overline R_1,\ldots,\overline R_n$, function symbols $\overline F_1,\ldots, \overline F_m$ and constant symbols $\overline c_i$. $L(\mathfrak A)$, moreover, has constant symbols $\overline a$ for all $a \in |\mathfrak A|$.

Then see page 67 :

> If $\varphi$ is a formula with free variables, say $FV(\varphi) = \{ z_1,\ldots, z_k \}$, then we say that $\varphi$ is *satisfied by* $a_1,\ldots, a_k \in |\mathfrak{A}|$ if $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \varphi[\overline a_1,\ldots, \overline a_k/z_1,\ldots, z_k]$ [...].

The definition of $\hat{\mathfrak{A}}$, page 112, is nothing new :

> Since we will often join all elements of $|\mathfrak A|$ to $\mathfrak A$ as constants, it is convenient to have a special notation for the enriched structure: $\hat{\mathfrak{A}} = (\mathfrak{A}, |\mathfrak{A}|)$.

Thus, we have that : $\hat{\mathfrak{A}} \vDash \varphi (\overline a_1,\ldots, \overline a_n)$ entails $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \varphi(\overline a_1,\ldots, \overline a_n)$ because the enriched strucure $\hat{\mathfrak{A}}$ is obtained from $\mathfrak{A}$ "adding" all the  $a \in |\mathfrak{A}|$ as *distinguished elements*.

In this way, for the strucuture $\hat{\mathfrak{A}} = (\mathfrak{A}, |\mathfrak{A}|)$, the two sets of *constants* [symbols] : $\{ \overline c_i |i \in I \}$ and $\{ \overline c_i |i \in I \} \cup \{ \overline a_i |$ for all $a \in |\mathfrak{A}| \}$ are the same.

What happened is that we have expanded the original language $L$ to $L'$, adding new *symbols* : a name for each object in the domain.

Having expanded the language, we have to expand also the strucuture, because a structure $\mathfrak A$ is a *domain* $A$ plus a function $\mathcal I$ "mapping" the symbols of the language into objects and subsets of $A$.

Thus, we have to extend the mapping $\mathcal I$ in order to take into account the new symbols of the expanded language : but the domain does not change.

See  C.C.Chang & H.Jerome Keisler, [Model Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486488217) (3rd ed - Dover reprint), page 21 :

> > The processes of expansion and reduction [of a model or structure] do not change the universe of the model.